# Move a value to another form using jQuery

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to filled a form value based on select option and I try to make a code like this:

This is the HTML code :

```
    <select id=“benih”>
    <option lama="6 bulan" berat="1kg" harga="Rp 45.000">Kacang</option>
    <option lama="5 bulan" berat="100kg" harga="Rp 700.000">Padi</option>
    <option lama="4 bulan" berat="2kg" harga="Rp 10.000">Semangka</option>
    <option lama="5 bulan" berat="3kg" harga="Rp 80.000">Semangka</option>
    <option lama="3 bulan" berat="4kg" harga="Rp 4.500">Timun</option>
</select>
<br>
Lama tanam <input type="text" id="lama-tanam" /><br>
Berat <input type="text" id="berat" /><br>
Harga <input type="text" id="harga" />
```

And jQuery looks like this:

```
     $("#benih").on("change", function(){

  // ambil nilai
  var lama = $("#benih option:selected").attr("lama");
  var berat = $("#benih option:selected").attr("berat");
  var harga = $("#benih option:selected").attr("harga");

  // pindahkan nilai ke input
  $("#lama-tanam").val(lama);
  $("#berat").val(berat);
  $("#harga").val(harga);

});
```

But it isn't working, what do i miss? or make a wrong??

Comment: The quotes you use are wrong... `“` and `”` aren't valid... Use `"`. The rest looks ok.

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette I'm already change it, but it isn't working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The quotes you use are wrong... `“` and `”` aren't valid... Use `"`. The rest **is** ok.

```js
$("#benih").on("change", function(){

  // ambil nilai
  var lama = $("#benih option:selected").attr("lama");
  var berat = $("#benih option:selected").attr("berat");
  var harga = $("#benih option:selected").attr("harga");

  // pindahkan nilai ke input
  $("#lama-tanam").val(lama);
  $("#berat").val(berat);
  $("#harga").val(harga);

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

Pilih Benih
<select id="benih">
    <option lama="6 bulan" berat="1kg" harga="Rp 45.000">Kacang</option>
    <option lama="5 bulan" berat="100kg" harga="Rp 700.000">Padi</option>
    <option lama="4 bulan" berat="2kg" harga="Rp 10.000">Semangka</option>
    <option lama="5 bulan" berat="3kg" harga="Rp 80.000">Semangka</option>
    <option lama="3 bulan" berat="4kg" harga="Rp 4.500">Timun</option>
</select>
<br>
Lama tanam <input type="text" id="lama-tanam" /><br>
Berat <input type="text" id="berat" /><br>
Harga <input type="text" id="harga" />
```